# Can't provision my Vagrant VM : Bad Interpreter (Chef solo - ruby)

Tags: ruby, nginx, vagrant, chef-solo, vagrantfile

This is the first time I'm using Vagrant, trying to get a debian machine set up with Java, Elasticsearch and Nginx! 
But I can't provision my vm. Here is the issue I have:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
Running chef-solo...
stdin: is not a tty
bash: /usr/bin/chef-solo: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

I don't know why it keeps telling me that chef-solo and ruby are located at those places because it's not the case. Is it on the client machine or on the host machine ?

I tried to change locations but didn't change the error message.

Here is my [Vagrantfile](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bb872f5de77c66cf3271)

Any idea guys?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: "No such file or directory" that mean "/usr/bin/ruby" is not existed, please check it